# What is the work flow of this Spring Boot program

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am a beginner in spring boot application and I recently came across this project having following 3 packages

> com.packagename.controller
>
> com.packagname.domain
>
> com.packagename.service

In *domain package*, there is a single class named **Student**
having the following code

```
private String name;

public Student() {
}

public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + "]";
}
```

Then in *Service package*,
  class **StudentService**

```
package com.javTpoint.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.javTpoint.domain.Student;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        student.setName(student.getName() + "123");
        return student;
    }
}
```

And finally in *Controller package*,
**Student class**

```
package com.javTpoint.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.javTpoint.domain.Student;
import com.javTpoint.service.StudentService;

@RestController
public class StudentController {
@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    Student saveStuden(@RequestBody Student student) {
    System.out.println(student);
        return studentService.saveStudent(student);
    }
}
```

The program asked to use this is *Postman*
I just want to understand the how the workflow is taking place like
why `@RequestBody` is used inside `saveStuden()` method in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Postman you likely invoke a URL such as `http://<host>:<port>/student` using the HTTP `POST` method to submit a payload (probably) expressed in JSON e.g.

```
{ "name": "aName" }
```

The flow from Postman goes like this:

1. Postman `POST`s the request body.
2. The application which exposes the `http://<host>:<port>/student` consumes the request, deserialises the request body into a `Student` object and delegates to an instance of `StudentController`. This: `@RequestBody Student student` instructs Spring to deserialise the given payload into an instance of `Student`.
3. The `StudentController` delegates to the instance of `StudentService` which it has been injected with. Note: the The `@Autowired` annotation instructs Spring's *dependency injection* mechanism to create an instance of `StudentController` with an instance of `StudentService` injected into it.
4. The `StudentService` appends "123" to the student name and returns the mutated `Student` instance.
5. The `StudentController` returns the mutated `Student` instance.
6. The framework (i.e. Spring Boot) serialises the returned `Student` and returns the serialised representation to Postman.

What you have described in your OP looks like a common division of responsibilities:

- The framework (Spring Boot in this case) provides the servlet container pieces and maps HTTP invocations to public methods on contoller classes
- The controller provides the HTTP endpoint integration and is typically a lightweight facade over a service
- The service is responsible for 'doing something' with the given object

---

**Update** in response to this comment:

> where should I learn what you know from? Any personal recommendations?

You could start with [this Spring Boot example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and walk through it step by step. Once you have it working (which typiclaly takes no more than 15 mins) then use ...

- Logging
- Debugging
- Changing things (one thing at a time) and observing cause-and-effect

...  to  help you understand what Spring is doing 'under the covers'.

Comment: And what is @Autowired annotation doing?
Also where should I learn what you know from? Any personal recommendations?

Comment: @Mr.J I have updated the answer to address your last comment and I have added some clarification on what `@Autowired` means.

Comment: Thanks! 
I downloaded the application through spring tool suite but I don't see any src/jmain/resources. I want to change the server port (earlier I did it making change in application.properties) But can't find it in that. What to do?

Comment: and what about the theory part? like Spring's dependency injection mechanism and stuff?

Comment: Do you mean "where should I learn what you know about _Spring's dependency injection mechanism_ from"? If so, then [read this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html).

Comment: why is this(the application in my code) considred a rest api?

Answer (score 1):

The `@RequestBody` annotation just before the `student` parameter means the `student` object will handle data you will send to `/student` uri via a `POST` request.

The data should be sent in JSON format:

for example:

```
{
    name: "Joe Doe"
}
```

The `studentService.saveStudent(student)`will alter the data of the `student` object and the output would be.

```
{
    name: "Joe Doe123"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Do you have any  personal recommendation where to learn spring from?